# @OnStateChanged for sequential state transitions in spring state machine

Tags: spring-statemachine

I want to define a sequential transition for my spring state machine. My state transitions are A -> B -> C. My business case is as below

I have single event E for transition to B from A and there is no event for B to C. I just want to define that if at all I am in B state I should perform the necessary actions and then move to state C without any event.

Below is the code snippet that I am using

```
transitions.withExternal().source(A).target(B).event(E)

transitions.withExternal().source(B).target(C)
```

The above transitions are taking state machine to C from A but the below onStateChanged method is first detecting change from B to C and then A to B.
Are the above transitions are correct or do we need other way to define those transitions

```
@OnStateChanged
public void anyStateChange() {}
```

Comment: The transitions are defined correctly. Why can't you use a "synthetic" event to transition from B to C?

Comment: Yeah i thought of that but was wandering if we have something provided by state-machine implementation